# Dynamically adding inflated views to ViewFlipper in Android causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, viewflipper, layout-inflater

I'm getting `NullPointerException` when I'm trying to programmatically add inflated views to my `ViewFlipper`:

-- onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.event_report);

final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.eventReportViewFlipper);

final View typeView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.event_report_type, null)
mFlipper.addView(typeView, VIEW_TYPE, null); //NullPointerException
```

-- event_report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/eventReportCaption"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/eventReportViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

-- event_report_type.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventReportViewTypeUpperLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventReportViewTypeLowerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I plan to initialize typeView later.

Here's my stack trace:

```
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3582)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3732)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:492)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:436)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1984)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1874)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.addView(ViewAnimator.java:160)
11-28 16:59:56.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8604):     at fi.emicode.flashpoint.EventDialog.onCreate(EventDialog.java:43)
```

Comment: Correct me. You pass null in parameters explicitly and then wonder why there's NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from android docs for addView method

```
addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

is VIEW_TYPE of type int?

I think you should specifiy the layoutparams for the added view or use addView with only
2 parameters

```
addView(VIEW_TYPE,index);
```